# How to avoid in this case the IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, adapter

I have `ListView` which shows, through an `Adapter`, the data from a global `ArrayList`. If I want to add an element to this `ArrayList` the proper approach is to do that in the main (UI) thread and immediately call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` afterwards, in order to avoid an *"IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification"*. However the `ArrayList` is changed in a secondary thread, executed by a `Service` which is not bound to the Activity all the time, and thus does not always have a reference to the `Adapter` in order to post these operations in the main thread queue. So when (I suppose) the main thread runs into the changed list, the exception ensues.

I see two ways of circumventing this:

1. Make the Adapter global so I can reference it any time I want.
2. Clone the list and make the `Adapter` backed by the clone. Thus when the original list is changed the clone will remain untouched until the moment the main thread needs to exhibit the changes (e.g. on `Activity.onResume()`), at which I update the clone based on the original and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The drawbacks of the second approach seem to be the apparently unnecessary redundancy and the memory overhead (although the list is not big, at maximum some 500 objects of 12 fields each). I tend to choose the first one, but which one do you find best? If there is a third approach, please let me know.

Comment: Have you considered a database or sharedpreferences?

Comment: I ended up serializing the global `ArrayList` for persisting its data across process kills, but I think changing the persistence approach would be too much a hassle at this point. And this is not the issue here, unless by adopting a different approach you mean using some alternate data consistency API I'm not aware of, such as a `Loader`.

Comment: Since you use service to load data, i also recommend to use database, and read it in your activity to show in listview.

Comment: In such case I would prefer a database approach. This method is clean & simple. There are always trade offs in engineering and software development

Comment: The problem I see in your current approach is that somehow, someday, you are going to need to do something else than reading that data, or just add a new type of data to this one (maybe that day is today? :)). I am unsure how you are going to deal with that with an arraylist. As for APIs, there is nothing I have in mind if you disregard either solutions. I guess you can stick with the global approach. Be careful with it, though.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. The persistence method is not an issue. Notifying the view that is listening to changes in the data structure is. I'm subclassing `BaseAdapter`, I'll have no issues if I need to change the class whose objects compose the `ArrayList` either (if that's what @YordanLyubenov means).

Comment: Well then, why don't you just add the data in a database (from the ArrayList), use a `CursorLoader` with a `ContentProvider` and forget about any problems related to listening changes?

Comment: @YordanLyubenov Thanks, I will research about them.

Answer (score 0):

As you've not shown your code, I don't know if this might help, but have you considered using a `CountDownLatch`? in the manual page comes a perfect example on blocking the execution of a thread until the Latch is released. You could simply declare an instance in your main Activity and pass a reference to the Service and other involved parts.

As your service is unbound, you might use a `BroadcastReceiver` to pass the instance to the service, or even using a `Semaphore` instead, as this last is serializable and thus able to be put as an extra to an `Intent` (you would need to bind the Service in that case, though).

Comment: From my understanding the operation that needs to await in this case is the main thread performing a UI update in a `ListView` and potentially bumping into an inconsistency between it and its backing data (the operation it would be going to wait for is `notifyDataSetChanged()` restoring that situation to a consistent state). I cannot insert a `CountDownLatch` before the operation that needs to wait. What I need to do is make sure `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called by the main thread right after that same thread changes the underlying data and before it has time to perform other UI operations.